# Perl: Extract distinct patterns from a string

Tags: regex, string, perl

I would like to extract patterns according to `a[a-z]` from a long string and output only distinct values. For example for the following string in `$x`

```
perl -e "$x = 'abx1acy2acz3ab'";
```

The results should be:

ab
   ac

Problem: There is no rule to split the record/string into an array which  makes it easy to extract the pattern.

Comment: IS there not a "set" DS in perl? That could probably help

Comment: @Predicate: We tend to use hashes to model sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you ever want unique data, consider using a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$_ = 'abx1acy2acz3ab';
my %seen;

for (/(a[a-z])/g) {
  say $_ unless $seen{$_}++;
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting: it is possible to screen over a string usnig `for`. I didn't know that. Very useful.

Comment: @giordano: You're not really iterating over the string. `/(...)/g` will return a list of matches and you're iterating over that list.

Answer (score 5):

You will get distinct patterns by this regex(if you don't care about their order):

```
(a[a-z])(?!.*\1)
```

**[click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSt781/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `(a[a-z])` - matches letter `a` followed by any other letter in range `a-z`. The contents are captured in Group 1
- `(?!.*\1)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the contents of group 1 are not present later in the string.

Comment: Thanks for this regexp and for expanation. How can I print each distinct pattern? `perl -e "$x = 'abx1acy2acz3ab'; $x =~ /(a[a-z])(?!.*\1)/g; print $1;"` prints only `ac`.

Comment: That's a quite clever solution!

Comment: @giordano.. you are doing a global search, so wrap it in a while loop ````perl -e '$x = "abx1acy2acz3ab"; while( $x =~ /(a[a-z])(?!.*\1)/g ) { print "$1\n" } '````

Answer (score 3):

Another Perl one-liner

```
$ perl -le ' $x="abx1acy2acz3ab" ;%kv=$x=~/(a[a-z])((?<=.))/g; $,="\n"; print keys %kv '
ac
ab

$
```

with another input:

```
$  perl -le ' $x="abxaxy2acz3ab" ; %kv=$x=~/(a[a-z])((?<=.))/g; $,="\n"; print keys %kv '
ax
ab
ac

$
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the input string is, for example, "abx1axy2acz3ab".

Comment: @Dave.. I just fixed.. could you please review

Comment: Thanks Dave.but onething surprising me.. I'm expecting the character that is matched with [a-z] to go into "values" of the hash.. but it is printing empty.. Any idea why it is empty string?

Comment: m//g return an list. You are getting 8 matches, every second one of which is empty ( `((?<=.))` ), and those are becoming your hash values.

Comment: This is an interesting way to use hash for uniqueness over all matches. So you care about keys here and thus all is well.  (And I don't get that empty line at the end of printout ?!)

Comment: @jhnc.. if I understand right, the positive lookbehind doesn't consume any string and so if any capture groups are covered with it, then those also doesn't consume..right?

Comment: If you really want to capture the values, then the capturing parens should go around the pattern itself (not the whole assertion): `/(a[a-z])(?<=(.))/g;`, for `perl -E'$_ = "abxaxyaczab"; %h = /(a[a-z])(?=(.))/g; say "$_ => $h{$_}" for keys %h'`

Comment: @stack0114106 With perl I tend to just try things rather than think too hard! :)  `perl -le ' $x="abxaxy2acz3ab" ; @g=($x=~/(a[a-z])((?<=.))/g); print"<<$_>>" for @g'`

Comment: @stack0114106 I liked your answer here, thanks for your time